# Date & Time Formula Field Issue?

Tags: formula, formula-field

I Want to display a value using formula field such it is a time ahead of created date.

I have another field called target field so I have to set the value of the formula field such that it equal to 50% of date/time between created date and target field.

Eg : 
CreateDate :  7/2/2017 10:47 AM
TargetDate :  7/2/2017 10:51 PM

The formula field should return : 7/2/2017 10:49 PM

I have created the formula-

`DATETIMEVALUE(CreatedDate + 0.5*(Target_Date_Time__c - CreatedDate))`

but this formula is returning : **7/2/2017 4:49 PM**

why is this happening?

I tried changing it to : **`DATETIMEVALUE(CreatedDate + 0.5*(Target_Date_Time__c - CreatedDate)+0.25)`** now it is returning the desired value

Can anyone explain why is it happening or any other formula to achieve this.

Comment: pay attention that 10:47 is AM and 10:51 is PM. I think that is a source of your misunderstood

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy Thank you very much It was a mere overlook